# how can i turn off the check model before generating code programatically

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

I want to turn on/off the parameter check model before generating code (shown below) through Matlab script. how can I achieve this? I am not finding the parameter name for that property.Any kind of help is appreciated.

[image]

Usually when I want to change a model parameter name I use this code.
Ex: want to set the Signal Range Checking parameter to warning.

```
set_param(test.mdl, 'SignalRangeChecking','warning');
```

So is there a property for check model before generating the code?

Comment: What is the actual parameter name? Is it one of the ones listed at http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model-parameters.html? Can you post a screenshot of the relevant window?

Comment: I don't know the parameter name else I could've used the same code to set it. Attached is the screen shot[screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/1zppa3p/8)

Comment: Thanks. Can you right-click on it and use the Context Menu to get the parameter name?

Comment: found the answer. thanks for that tip. it will be very usefull for further parameters!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for :

```
set_param(yourModelName, 'CheckMdlBeforeBuild', 'OFF');
```

Answer (score 2):

right-click on it and use the Context Menu to get the parameter name - @am304